# How i can get .txt file read line by line

Tags: character, line

I have a file on the SDcard - "file.txt" containing telephone numbers in separate line.
I want to display line first, and then if I press a button, the second line should be displayed in the TextView and the first line should disappear. 
I have code that simply reads the contents of txt file and fully insert all rows in TextView:

How should I change this code to the serial output the following line when you press the button????

```
    File sdcard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
    File file = new File(sdcard,"file.txt");
    StringBuilder text = new StringBuilder();
        try {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
        String line;

        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            line = br.readLine();
            text.append(line);
            text.append('\n');
        }
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
    }
    tv.setText(text);
```

How should I change this code to the serial output the following line when you press the button????

Answer (score 0):

You could store the content of the file in ArrayList< String> , and then, upon pressing a button, change the text in your TextView to another in the list. Something like:

1. Reading file and storing in a list:

   ```
   //make this a class member variable
   List<String> numbers = new ArrayList<String>();

   while((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
       //store each line in our list as separate entry
       numbers.add(line);
   }
   ```
2. Updating TextView upon button press:

   ```
   //make this a class member variable
   //this is being used to get the line from list
   int currentLine = 0;

   button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
       @Override
       public void onClick(View v) {
           //set the text
           tv.setText(numbers.get(currentLine));

           //increment currentLine
           currentLine++;

           //make sure we don't go beyond the number of lines stored in the list
           //so if we reach the last index, we start from the beginning
           if (currentLine == numbers.size()) {
               currentLine = 0;
           }
       }
   });
   ```